# Why doesn't go my props to child component when I changed my props in Main Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

When I change my state, I can read newData in Main Component but my update state doesn't go my ChildComponent. I read only initialData in my ChildComponent. Why doesn't go my new props to ChildComponent? or Why doesn't reRender my ChildComponent ?

```
class Main extends Component{
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: "initalData",
        }
}

componentDidMount(){
this.changeState();
}

changeState(){
this.setState({data: "newData"})
}

render(){
console.log("my data in Main :",this.state.data)
return(
<ChildComponent dataProps={this.state.data}>
)
}

class ChildComponent extends Component{
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const getData = props.dataProps;
        console.log("getData is ",getData)
        this.state = {
          ...,
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's because the `constructor` of the class component only run once when you initialize it but not every render.**

To always get the latest value, you would need to put them inside the class component body below the constructor.

Something like this:

```
class ChildComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            ...
          }
  }

  const getData = this.props.dataProps;
  console.log("getData is ", getData)

  render() (
    ...
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below to update each time props that get passed to it changes

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot){
    if(prevProps !== this.props){
    this
  }
}
```

[ComponentDidUpdate docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)